# How to get target method of a given JAX-RS request?

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy, introspection

Is there a way to obtain the `java.lang.reflect.Method` of the method (which is annotated with `@Path`) which will be called for a given `HttpServletRequest`?

Here is my use case : I'm in a Java EE `Filter` and want to know if the method which will be invoked later is annotated with another specific annotations.

(I'm using RESTEasy 3.0.7)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's easy if you can use a [ContainerRequestFilter](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html) instead of a normal Servlet Filter.

```
@Provider
public class SomeFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        Method method = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod();
    }

}
```

Comment: Seems nice. But the problem is that I'm in a Servlet Filter, and must be because the goal of that Servlet Filter is to create a `Principal` to pass to the `FilterChain` overriding `HttpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal()`...

Comment: You can also set the SecurityContext for the current request per ```requestContext.setSecurityContext()``` in a ContainerRequestFilter.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. But I must insert my Filter just before another which use `HttpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal()` in order to know the actual authenticated user... The best would be a method which could give me a `ResourceInfo` provided a `HttpServletRequest`.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Your filter must be executed before RESTeasy comes into play. (It does not make sense to do authentication afterwards). But your filter may change some Headers, QueryParameters or even redirect. So in your filter it's not clear which Method will be invoked finally.

Comment: It worked. I finally did a `request.setAttribute("specificMarker", Boolean.TRUE)` in the filter and tested the target method in the `ContainerRequestFilter` I created, and checked the marker like that : `requestContext.getProperty("specificMarker")`